# Which is the best ?xml parser for android or Regex for stripping out xml?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I want to strip out the tags  from this page http://ptwc.weather.gov/feeds/ptwc_rss_indian.xml

Just I want to take the content between description tags in the above xml

a)For this whether I can use xml parser or regex

b) If I use regex how to strip out that? (I used the below code but it's not working

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("<description>(.*)</description>",Pattern.DOTALL);
        //Matcher matcher=p.matcher(result);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(result);

        if (matcher.matches())
        {
            String s1=matcher.group(1);
            textView.setText(s1);
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText("No Matches);
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to parse XML (org.w3c.Document) on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927406/way-to-parse-xml-org-w3c-document-on-android) . Besides, you're not looking to compare xml parsers, but asking how to parse a document. The title is misleading.

Comment: I just want to know is it good to use xml parsers or I can use a regex to strip out the tags?

Answer (score 1):

You should always use an XML parser. It is much safer and in the end easier to implement. An expression that might work in your tests may break with a nested tag or a minor change in the structure. Also, XML is much more maintainable should you want to retrieve more data from the same files.

**Use an XML Parser!**

Edit: read [an interesting discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=668353)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Aleadam in that you should always use an XML Parser but I also believe that an XML parser should not be a hassle to write or use which is why I always recommend using the [Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) on Android.

So much so that I even wrote a blog post on [how to use Simple in Android](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).