# android and xml pharsing. which way is the best and ideal?

Tags: android, xml

when it comes to pulling XML data from a website or file what is the fastest and best way? i know there is SAX and such but before i start building an application i wanna use the most ideal way and learn on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931678/which-is-the-best-xml-parser-for-android-or-regex-for-stripping-out-xml and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926367/android-best-xml-parsing-library

Answer (score 0):

[It's important to understand the difference between SAX and DOM. It's explained here.](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/04/sax-vs-dom-differences-between-dom-and.html)