# Writing to an existing resource XML file in Android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-file

I am trying to write to an existing XML file in the /res/xml directory on an Android device. Two questions:

1) Are these files able to be overwritten? 
2) If so, how can I obtain a handle to that file?

I am trying this to no avail:

```
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {
        fos = openFileOutput("/res/xml/scores.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(writer.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

UPDATE

Trying to read from the file using:

```
....
        PriorityQueue<Score> scores = new PriorityQueue<Score>();
    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFac = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser qXML = xmlFac.newPullParser();
    File scoresFile = new File(c.getExternalFilesDir(null), "scores.xml");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(scoresFile);
    qXML.setInput(is,null);
....
```

Trying to write to the file using:

```
....
    File scoresFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "scores.xml");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(scoresFile);

    os.write(writer.toString().getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
....
```

Comment: honestly if you're trying to do this then you should think of another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) on the device. You can't and shouldn't be writing to the resources. Instead, copy the resource to the external storage, and then modify it there.

**EDIT**: You can also use your application's [internal data folder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) to save files to, but again, you will want to copy your resource there if you want to modify it. This will allow the files to remain internal to your application.

Comment: Only use external storage if you don't mind the idea that any other app on the device will be able to see, read, and possibly modify the file.

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thank you.

Comment: Can I use an XmlResourceParser on xml files in those areas? The "Resource" part in the middle of that class name makes me think not.

Comment: To use an XmlResourceParser on a non-resource file, you could create a new `XmlPullParser` using the [`XmlPullParserFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserFactory.html) class and then call the [`setInput()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#setInput%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) ([found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927406/way-to-parse-xml-org-w3c-document-on-android/1927554#1927554)).

Comment: Fantastic. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @mopsled ... I appreciate your help, but I am still a bit confused as to how to write to files. I read up on the internal data folder link and the XmlPullParserFactory and setInput methods, but how do I define a filename that I want these things to write to? Say I want to save this XML file to scores.xml... who would I go about setting that up? Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my original post with what I have attempted to do in order to read/write the file... it does not appear to be working. When I try to read from the file, mScores is always null. Should the null in the getExternalFilesDir(null) be changes to something else? Not sure what this argument represents.