# How to store data in an XML document?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem: how can I to write / update data in an XML document.

Path of XML file: `MyProject/res/xml/contacts.xml`

Example of xml code:

```
<contacts>
    <contact choise="0" phone="0" />
</contacts>
```

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835339/writing-to-an-existing-resource-xml-file-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please know that res files are static and cant be changed during runtime. Its not preferable too. Better you can save it in your internal files where your database exists, copy it into sdcard, edit it and push it back ti internal memory and delete the file from sdcard.