# How to read xml file in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've the following xml file inside the /mnt/sdcard. I want to get the version of the `item type=provider` from the following file. The file is big(500 lines) which has othere types also. This is simplified file. In the file I'm intetersted in this node:

```
<Item Type="Provider" Version="19.0.0.0"Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" FileSize="2746200" />
```

From this node I want to get the version i.e. 19.0.0.0.

Here is my xml file:

```
<Manifest guid="FD29E1EF-A5C4-4D19-ACC8-8C98C7E91B02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PackageType="Full" Scope="APPROVED">
   <Items>
        <Item id="fcxm-8ikj-olk-ffgcxh3" Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" value="f425921f-b6ef-4e58-8a14-fcbd0d7e50e9" />
        <Item Type="question" Version="19.0.0.0"Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" FileSize="2746200" />
        <Item Type="Provider" Version="19.0.0.0"Checksum="EShHVeNtW1xTfEvLvATwqA==" FileSize="2746200" />
    </Items>
</Manifest>
```

I'm using Java code to develop my android application. I searched on the internet, I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138754/getting-an-attribute-value-in-xml-element) which is iterating to all the nodes of item type. I dont want want to iterate.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html here is link to devoloper site

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1927406/1531054

Comment: That link is good. Why you dont want to iterate.?

Comment: Hi you are having better example in following tutorial http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Comment: and try with this also. http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=fb9b1b6d-3ac8-4eb3-a6bc-6b5c914c83c6

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj I dont want to iterate because my xml has more than 500 nodes of type `<item type="">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in android we have three normal way to parse xml, `XmlPullParser`, `SaxXmlPullParser`, `DocumentBuilder(DOM parser)`, and android use `XmlPullParser` for android resource parser.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can u please tell me which would be good specific to this example, and how to read the file?