# extract text from a long string and store in variables

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am working on an android project for school.  We are given escaped xml in an editText, I can read the text out of the editText but what I want to is to capture values out of it. so for example this is in the editText:

```
&lt;ResponseSummary&gt; 
&lt;ID&gt;spq789pie&lt;/ID&gt; 
&lt;No&gt;305&lt;/No&gt; 
&lt;ItemCount&gt;1&lt;/ItemCount&gt; 
&lt;Total&gt;1.00&lt;/Total&gt; 
&lt;/ResponseSummary&gt;
```

what I plan to do is `String response = edtResponse.getText().toString()` to capture the txt out of the editText. what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
string test = (some expression that searches text and return a value text from a string)
if (test = "ID"){setID(ID);}
else if(No = "No"){setNo(No);}
else if(ItemCount = "ItemCount"){setItemCount(ItemCount);}
else if(Total = "Total"){setTotal(Total);}
```

Based on the above xml I'd like the values to look like this at the end:

```
ID = spq789pie
No = 305
ItemCount = 1
Total = 1.00
```

If you could help me out I'd really appreciate it.  I have read that a regex work but I'm not very good with regex. If there is another method I'd take that as well.

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to parse XML (org.w3c.Document) on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927406/way-to-parse-xml-org-w3c-document-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:&lt;ResponseSummary&gt;|(?!^)\\G)\\s*"
                          + "&lt;(?<key>(?>[^&]++|&(?!gt;))*)&gt;"
                          + "(?<value>(?>[^&]++|&(?!lt;))*)"
                          + "&lt;/\\1&gt;").matcher(txt);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group("key") + " = " + m.group("value"));
}
```

The `\G` anchor stands for *start of the string* or *end of the last match*. The negative lookahead `(?!^)` is used to exclude the first case.

Comment: +1 for an answer that the prof will look at and think "Plagiarism" and will find on the first page of Google.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are already in XML format, I would recommend an XML parser, rather than using regex. Android has a built in parser called [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), which is pretty easy to use.

Here is a more in-depth guide to XML parsing on Android: [Parsing XML Data | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with this as a string and not as with XML as [savanto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23449561/1993204) suggested, you can do it like this (using as simple regexes as possible):

```
    String[] lines = response.split("[\n]");
        // you split the string to lines (new line char is the thing that splits the string)

    String[] line = null;
    String key = null;
    String closureKey = null;
    String strValue = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        line = lines[i].split("[&][lg][t][;]");
            // you split every single line with specific string:
            // first char is '&', second char is either 'l' or 'g'
            // third char is 't', forth is ';'

        key = line[1];
            // line array will start and end with an empty string so you take the element with index 1, NOT 0

        if (i == 0)
        {
            // do so something with the parent key
        }
        else if (i == lines.length - 1)
        {
            // check if parent closure key is correct
        }
        else
        {
            strValue = line[2];
            closureKey = line[3];

            if (key.equals("ID"))
            {
                // do something; value is in strValue
            }
            else if (key.equals("ItemCount"))
            {
                // do something; value is in strValue
            }
            //and so on...


            if (!closureKey.equals("/" + key))
            {
                // something is wrong with this child's closure key
            }
        }
    }
```